# cannot convert 'QScopedPointer<T>' to 'QStandardItem *'

Tags: qt, qstandarditem, qscopedpointer

I use this code without any error

```
QStandardItem *newRow;
newRow = new QStandardItem(hostname);
model2->setItem(index, 2, newRow);
```

I want to change the above code to the below:

```
QScopedPointer<QStandardItem> newRow(new QStandardItem);
model2->setItem(index, 2, newRow);
```

But I get this error:

```
C:\...\mainwindow.cpp:352: error: C2664: 'void QStandardItemModel::setItem(int,int,QStandardItem *)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'QScopedPointer<T>' to 'QStandardItem *'
with
[
    T=QStandardItem
]
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, use take() method to get the pointer.

On my computer

```
QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem("foo");
       model->setItem(4,0,item2);//works

QScopedPointer<QStandardItem> newRow(new QStandardItem("foo"));
       model->setItem(4,0,newRow.take());//works too
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `QScopedPointer<T>::take()` which releases the stored pointer of the scoped pointer container i suggest to use `QScopedPointer<T>::data()` which returns a the pointer but does not reset the scoped pointer

But on the other hand, why would you like to use `QScopedPointer` to store a pointer to the `QStandardItem` when the model will take ownership of it and will handle its lifetime?